# How to make animations run separately?

Tags: android, animation

I am moving an object around the screen using animations but the animation seem to run at the same time. For example, when i choose up and down the object stays put. With 2 ups and a down the object moves up 1. I'd like it to move up 1, then down 1 and up 1 again. Any way to do this? Here is my code:

```
                int totalx = 0;
                int totaly = 0;

                for (int j=0; j<moves.size(); j++){

                if (moves.get(j).equals("up")) {
                    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0 , 0, -(63+totaly));
                    animation.setDuration(1000);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    circle.startAnimation(animation);
                    totaly = totaly - 63;


                }
                else if (moves.get(j).equals("down")) {
                    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0 , 0, (63+totaly));
                    animation.setDuration(1000);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    circle.startAnimation(animation);
                    totaly = totaly + 63;

                }
                else if (moves.get(j).equals("left")) {
                    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -63 , 0, -(63+totaly));
                    animation.setDuration(1000);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    circle.startAnimation(animation);
                    totalx = totalx + 63;

                }
                else if (moves.get(j).equals("right")) {
                    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 63 , 0, (63+totaly));
                    animation.setDuration(1000);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    circle.startAnimation(animation);
                    totalx = totalx + 63;

                }
                    }
```

Comment: What is your minimum SDK version?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use an `AnimationSet` for chaining the individual `Animations`.

```
AnimatorSet s = new AnimatorSet();
s.play(anim2).after(anim1);
```

This guide will help you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.Builder.html

Comment: Note that this only works on API 11+, and requires OP to refactor his code to use `Animator`s instead of `Animation`s.